# Launch an application and send it to second monitor

Tags: vb.net, multiple-monitors

In VB 2008, I am using the class 'process' to launch and external application with a few parameters. Does anybody knows how can I send it programmatically to second monitor?

Also, is there any way to know how many monitors are activated?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Launch an application and send it to second monitor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113/c-sharp-launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor)

Answer (score -2):

You can locate your form on a different screen.

```
form.Location = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Location + new Point(100, 100)
```

When you launch an application, use the Process Handle to get the Window (hWnd). It's this hWnd value that windows API uses.

You will need to use the SetWindowRect method imported from User32.dll (see last link)

See also

- [Screen Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(VS.71).aspx)
- [VB .NET Dual Monitor](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/d867a0cd-1f08-4f16-a8aa-db6ff77b3656)
- [Get Window Handles Associated With Process in vb.net](http://kellychronicles.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!A0D71E1614E8DBF8!217.entry)
- [Egghead Cage - hwnd position](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=33748717&threadid=33748670)
- [MSDN - SetWindowRect API Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188455(office.10).aspx)

Comment: Well, I know I can move a form of my application, but what I want to know is how to move the application launched by my program.