# Opening 2 Chrome windows on Separate monitors BUT with localstorage

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, local-storage, google-chrome-storage

I need to open 2 chrome windows in kiosk mode (or just fullscreen) on two separate monitors with a single click (.bat file)

This has been somewhat covered in [How to open two instances of Chrome kiosk mode in different displays (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294045/how-to-open-two-instances-of-chrome-kiosk-mode-in-different-displays-windows)

BUT:

The my web app running in the browser uses localstorage to transfer data from one chrome window to the other.
So we can't use the --user-data-dir= startup flag which creates completely isolated instance of Google Chrome window.

-- The computer is running on Windows 10

Can somebody suggest another solution?

Thank you

Comment: Searching the web I found: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage . Can I run the the windows using "app" mode and than exchange data using chrome.storage API?

Comment: something like this? `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --chrome --fullscreen --kiosk www.somesite.com`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Where is the part, where you move the window to secondary monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using automation software that opened both instances of Chrome browser window and moved them in their specified display (by number of X pixels)

The software I used is AutoHotKey (AHK) https://autohotkey.com/ - only for Windows.
You can use preinstalled Automator on Mac.

The script for AHK I wrote for my specific case:

```
Run, chrome.exe https://domain1/
WinWait, Titlebar Primary - Google Chrome
WinMove, 1920, 0  ; Move window by 1920px on X axis
Sleep, 1000

Run, chrome.exe https://domain2/
WinWait, Titlbar Secondary - Google Chrome
WinMove, 0, 0
WinActivate, Titlebar Secondary - Google Chrome
Sleep, 1000
Send, {F11}

Sleep, 1000
WinActivate, Titlebar Primary - Google Chrome
Send, {F11}
```

It identifies each window by name or "Titlebar".

The AHK software allows to create a single file that you can click on or make the script run at system startup.