# Is there a way to auto open an excel file and move it to the right monitor?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, powershell, sendkeys

I have a VacationCalendar PC that has 2 monitors. I also have 2 excel spreadsheets, a LEFT and a RIGHT. I am wanting to open up the RIGHT spreadsheet and move it over to the RIGHT screen when the script is ran.

Excel does remember it's last windows position, but it does not do it for individual spreadsheets from my testing, it will always open the spreadsheet on the last monitor that the software was open in.

Here is my current batch script:

```
@echo off
start excel.exe "C:\Users\vacationcalendar\Desktop\VacationCalendar_RIGHT.xlsx"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
powershell -Command "(new-object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys('{ESC}')"
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
powershell -Command "(new-object -ComObject WScript.Shell).SendKeys('{#}{SHIFT}{RIGHT}')"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak >nul
start excel.exe "C:\Users\vacationcalendar\Desktop\VacationCalendar_LEFT.xlsx"
```

It opens the right file, then waits 5 seconds and then sends a keypress of ESC. It does this because when the excel file opens, a cell is highlighted. But I don't believe it is working, because when it sends the {#}{SHIFT}{RIGHT} keystroke, it puts the '#' symbol into the highlighted cell.

The {#}{SHIFT}{RIGHT} keystroke is supposed to represent WINKEY + SHIFT + RIGHT ARROW to move the window the the right monitor.

What could I do better/learn to get this to work?

VBA Macro I tried:

```
Sub OpenAndPositionWorkbooks()
Dim ExcelApp As Object
Dim Workbook1 As Object
Dim Workbook2 As Object

' Create a new instance of Excel
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = True

' Open the first workbook and position it on the left monitor
Set Workbook1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\whull\Desktop\VacationCalendar_LEFT.xlsx")
Workbook1.Windows(1).WindowState = xlMaximized
Workbook1.Windows(1).Left = 0

' Open the second workbook and position it on the right monitor
Set Workbook2 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\whull\Desktop\VacationCalendar_RIGHT.xlsx")
Workbook2.Windows(1).WindowState = xlMaximized
Workbook2.Windows(1).Left = Screen.Width \ Screen.TwipsPerPixelX

' Release objects
Set Workbook1 = Nothing
Set Workbook2 = Nothing
Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You appear to be asking about using SendKeys in Windows and potentially, although unlikely, PowerShell. There is no question about Excel or a batch file here, so I have replaced two of your question tags accordingly.

Comment: Would you be interested in a VBA solution. The code will reside in the Excel File. The moment you open the file, based on the name, it iwll automatically move to the relevant monitor...

Comment: @Compo: I think it is about Excel. The batch file is created specifically for Excel. But then I could be wrong.... :)

Comment: @Compo, I feel my initial tags were correct as I am using excel sheets and I am using a batch script to call said excel sheets. But I am open to opinions.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I am open to a VBA solution, I have attempted that as well, but did not have any luck. I will update the question with the Macro I tried to use.

Comment: The OP did not submit a problem with their batch file or with Excel. They just wanted to know how to pass the WINKEY + SHIFT + RIGHT ARROW  sequence to a GUI program using SendKeys. All of the rest was irrelevant, other than for context. Now they have added a vba code snippet to their question, they should have updated the tags to reflect that, i.e. Excel and VBA! I have done that for them now.

Comment: I should say however, that this is now an unfocused programming problem, as there are now two completely different pieces of code, which are reportedly not working. The entire question is essentially about performing a specific task/project and the programming language or method is irrelevant to the OP. It has ventured beyond StackOverflow, into a Super User question.

Comment: @Compo, how should I proceed with this as I have laid out everything I have done. Part of the rules of this community is to do your own research and solve the task before coming to the community, I am only providing the steps I have taken to get to my goal and I am coming to the community for help. If this question needs to be asked somewhere else, I will gladly do that. But there have been similar questions to this asked here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294045/how-to-open-two-instances-of-chrome-kiosk-mode-in-different-displays-windows)

Comment: These are the general steps: Decide on how you want to perform the task. Once you've done that, write your code, test it, and if it fails to do what was intended, submit a [mcve], with all the information we need to replicate the single reported problem. You've done most of the steps, but without the important first one. Make that decision, then remove everything unrelated to that code example, and add any relevant environment, debugging, and output information etc.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I'm not sure where you got the {#} = Windows Key, but I found here (and tested myself) that it is ^{ESC} on Windows 10 stackoverflow.com/a/63544023/8678978

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. This will move the Excel file to the Right Monitor. I have tried it and it works. I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it.

**Important Note**: Since we are using VBA code, your files need to be saved as `.xlsm` and not `.xlsx`

**In the ThisWorkbook Code module.**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const SWP_NOSIZE As Long = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOACTIVATE As Long = &H10
Private Const SWP_NOZORDER As Long = &H4

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim leftPos As Long
    Dim appHwnd As Long
    
    '~~> Get the left position of the second monitor
    leftPos = GetSecondMonitorLeft()
    
    If leftPos = -1 Then
        MsgBox "No second monitor detected.", vbInformation
    Else
        '~~> Get the handle of the Excel application window
        appHwnd = Application.hwnd
        
        '~~> This is important because you can't move a maximized window
        Application.WindowState = xlNormal
        
        '~~> Move the application window to the second monitor
        SetWindowPos appHwnd, 0, leftPos, 0, 0, 0, _
        SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_NOACTIVATE
        
        '~~> Maximize the application window
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    End If
End Sub
```

**In a normal Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "user32" Alias _
"GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumDisplayMonitors Lib "user32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, _
ByVal lprcClip As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnEnum As LongPtr, ByVal dwData As LongPtr) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetMonitorInfo Lib "user32.dll" Alias _
"GetMonitorInfoA" (ByVal hMonitor As LongPtr, ByRef lpmi As Any) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Type monitorInfo
    cbSize As Long
    rcMonitor As RECT
    rcWork As RECT
    dwFlags As Long
End Type

Private Const SM_CMONITORS As Long = 80

'~~> This function gets the .Left of the 2nd monitor
Public Function GetSecondMonitorLeft() As Long
    Dim monitorCount As Integer
    Dim monitorInfo As monitorInfo
    Dim hdc As LongPtr
    Dim monCount As Long
    
    monitorInfo.cbSize = Len(monitorInfo)
    hdc = 0
    
    '~~> This will get the number of monitors
    monitorCount = GetSystemMetrics32(SM_CMONITORS)
    
    '~~> Check if there are at least 2 monitors
    If monitorCount >= 2 Then
        '~~> Get the information of the second monitor
        EnumDisplayMonitors 0, ByVal 0, AddressOf MonitorEnumProc, VarPtr(monitorInfo)
        
        monCount = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.Left
    Else
        '~~> If there is only 1 monitor, return -1
        monCount = -1
    End If
    
    GetSecondMonitorLeft = monCount
End Function

Private Function MonitorEnumProc(ByVal hMonitor As LongPtr, ByVal hdcMonitor As LongPtr, _
ByVal lprcMonitor As LongPtr, ByVal dwData As LongPtr) As Long
    Dim monitorInfo As monitorInfo
    
    monitorInfo.cbSize = Len(monitorInfo)
    GetMonitorInfo hMonitor, monitorInfo
    
    '~~> Here we copy the monitor info to the provided structure
    CopyMemory ByVal dwData, monitorInfo, Len(monitorInfo)
    
    '~~> Next enumeration
    MonitorEnumProc = 1
End Function
```

**Sample File:**

You can download a sample file from [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/iul1mh6ah5f5dmhdksaim/RIGHT.xlsm?rlkey=dgwf21jhu8n9j464rb7m2y509&dl=0) to test it.

**Followup**:

To open the Excel file in the left window, use this code. I tested it and it works.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim leftPos As Long
    Dim appHwnd As Long
    
    '~~> Get the left position of the second monitor
    leftPos = -1
    
    '~~> Get the handle of the Excel application window
    appHwnd = Application.Hwnd
        
    '~~> This is important because you can't move a maximized window
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
        
    '~~> Move the application window to the second monitor
    SetWindowPos appHwnd, 0, leftPos, 0, 0, 0, _
    SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_NOACTIVATE
        
    '~~> Maximize the application window
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

Comment: I downloaded the file you shared and I am trying to view the macro, but when I go to the view macro tab, I can't see anything listed there. I would like to edit it to have a file that will open on the LEFT and one to open on the RIGHT.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, I was able to successfully replicate this. What line would I need to change to make a LEFT file to open on the left, and is there a way to put the excel sheet into full size mode using CTRL + SHIFT + F1

Comment: **What line would I need to change to make a LEFT file to open on the left** Hard code the value in `leftPos = GetSecondMonitorLeft()`. For example `leftPos = 5` **is there a way to put the excel sheet into full size mode using CTRL + SHIFT + F1** You mean like this? :) `Application.DisplayFullScreen = True`

Comment: Full screen mode is working great, but it is still opening on the right monitor. I want the left file to open on the right and not the left. I hard coded leftPos = 5, but it still moves it to the right.

Comment: What happens when you use `leftPos = -1`. Soory I am out. can't test it.

Comment: It gives message box of 'No second monitor detected'

Comment: You forgot to remove the `If leftPos = -1 Then` check ;)

Comment: Even after all of that, it still opens on the right side. Is there something else that is setting the window position?

Comment: I just tested it and it works...    `leftPos = -1` and then `appHwnd = Application.hwnd` and the rest of the code in the workbook open

Comment: Can you share the file? The first one where it moves the excel spreadsheet from the LEFT monitor to the RIGHT monitor is great! But let's reverse it, if the LEFT spreadsheet is on the RIGHT monitor, I now want it to go to the LEFT. Doing as you suggested, only maximizes it on the window that the spreadsheet is on. Not actually moving the spreadsheet to the left monitor like the other file is doing. The other file will move the spreadsheet to the correct RIGHT monitor, I am now trying to accomplish that with the LEFT monitor now.

Comment: did you have a chance to look at this?

Comment: Sorry I was travelling. I have updated the post above with the code that I am using. See the `Followup` above.

Comment: In 'Display, I have the left monitor as '2' and right monitor as '1', If I change these arround to be: Left = 1, Right = 2. It now works great. BUT, now the RIGHT file is broken, it opens on the LEFT now as well. I am not sure if there is a way to specify, "Open on monitor '2' or '1'". Is that a thing? If you have 2 files, 1 that opens on the left always and one that opens on the right always, could you provide the files?