# Open browser window on dual monitors

Tags: windows, scripting

My client has dual monitors which they use to display two different websites in a public space. They want to be able to hard reboot the system and have it automatically start two browser windows, one on each monitor, and go to the appropriate websites.

We can get the browsers to start easily enough using the startup folder, but have not been able to figure out how to get one browser window to go to one screen, and the other window to the other screen automatically. Is there a way of doing this in powershell, or some other scripting language?

We are running Windows with IE, but also have Firefox installed.

Comment: Probably a better question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Ok, I'll copy it across

Answer (score 2):

You can create windows service that start automatically. It's simple. You will need .Net framework and install your windows service

also see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3750196/4810628