# VB.net move application to a different monitor

Tags: vb.net, monitors

In VB.net is there a way to move a focused application to a different monitor
For example, if Google Chrome was open on the primary monitor and in focus, would it be possible to move it to the second screen?

Comment: This should get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113/launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor

Comment: Thank you, I dont fully understand how to use any of the commands seen in that thread in VB.net as that is all C# and VB.net doesnt seem to have the same commands

Comment: The functions used there are not C# specific but they are part of the Windows API. I recommend to follow some basic tutorials on how to use this before attempting your task. It's not that hard but may be intimidating if you've never used it before.

Comment: thank you, any recommended tutorials?