# How to open a file from explorer onto specific monitors at max window size?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is what I have so far, but it only opens on the primary monitor.  My goal specifically is to open the file on the monitor associated with the button that I click.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point btnTopLeft = new Point(15, 15);
        foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = screen.DeviceName;
            btn.Size = new Size(100, 23);
            btn.Location = btnTopLeft;


            btn.Tag = screen;
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;

            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            btnTopLeft.Offset(0, btn.Height + 7);
        }
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == null || !(sender is Button))
            return;
        var btn = (Button)sender;

        if (btn.Tag == null || !(btn.Tag is Screen))
            return;
        var screen = (Screen)btn.Tag;

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"c:\");

    }
```

Comment: You want to "Open a file"?  Or do you just mean open Explorer in a particular directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch an application and send it to second monitor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113/launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Screen.GetBounds`method.

I believe this would give you which monitor your button mostly-is on
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6dba0zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And this will give you which monitor a Rectangle is mostly-on
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z2btd02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can also give it a Point, and it will return which monitor the point is on.

Once you figure out which monitor it is on, you could then use the `Screen` class again to get the bounds of the monitor and set your application's bounds to that.

Ex.

```
   this.Bounds = Screens.AllScreens[1].Bounds;
```

This is how I'd approach it first, though there may be a better way. Hope this helps.