# Disable second screen in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, screen

I come here because I have to, on a project, block access to windows users to applications.

I have a client/server architecture, with a client listening on a port. When the server sends a message, the client must open a WPF window, with the message sent by the server. (message such as "Fire Alert","Terrorist Attack" or other). So, my WPF has to make more than sixty percent of the screen, be in the foreground.

For the moment, I've put my form in TopMode, with a size that makes sixty percent of the screen.

```
this.Height = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * 0.60);
this.Width = (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * 0.60);
WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
this.Topmost = true;
```

The problem is when there is a split screen (or more than two screens), I can't block the second screen. So I thought about disabling the second screen, but I didn't find much on the internet.

So I'm here to ask for advice, do you know if that's possible? Do you have any other ideas?

Thank you !

Comment: I forgot to change it in code world ^^'

Comment: You could [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113/launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor) but to force it to monitor 1

Comment: Why do you want to stop access to applications?

Comment: Making your form cover parts of the screen does not prevent access to anything as the user can just kill your application. Consider another approach.

Comment: @m.rogalski after question update, your comment seems kind of confusing :)

Comment: @SeM-ՍեՄ Ah, yes. I haven't seen that it was updated.

Comment: AFAIK there is a special mode for this in windows. In German it's called "Kiosk Mode" ...

Comment: @Fildor Kiosk mode in English too

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shared-pc

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I just saw it. Sounded a bit too "German" for me to consider it to be the common name for the functionality. :D

Comment: Most of the workstations are on windows 7 :/

Comment: There you go: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2012/08/03/building-public-kiosk-workstations-with-windows-7-and-windows8-itpro/

Comment: @Equalsk The objective is not to block the user, but really to display a message, disabling the second screen, to show clearly that it is necessary to stop working.

Comment: _"to display a message, disabling the second screen, to show clearly that it is necessary to stop working"_ - Oh, then Kiosk is not for you anyway. Can you give a little more context?

Comment: So you want to display a large message on each screen? You can use the [Screen.AllScreens Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx) as a starting point, once you have this information the rest should be straightforward.

Comment: I have a client/server architecture, with a client listening on a port. When the server sends a message, the client must open a WPF window, with the message sent by the server. (message such as "Fire Alert","Terrorist Attack" or other).

So, my WPF has to make more than sixty percent of the screen, be in the foreground. That's why I'm worried about the second screen.

Comment: This is all information that should have been in your question along with a tag for `WPF`. This is why you have so many comments guessing at what you want rather than an answer. Hint: Edit this new information into your question.

Comment: When I count the number of screens with the Allscreens function and Length, I only have one screen, it does not detect my second screen :/

Comment: @Y.op why not simply open 1 window per screen you detect so you make sure it's displayed everywhere no matter the user setup.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, but I can't find much to open the form on all screens.

Comment: How are your screens set up? And how are your monitors connected to your machine? Can you reproduce the behavior on other machines? Are there machines, where `AllScreens` works as expected?

Comment: Allscreen detects well my second screen, now I have to find out how to open my application on the different screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block access outside the form you need to make your form modal.

Here is how to do it:

```
Form f = new Form();
 f.TopMost = true;
 f.ShowDialog()
```

Or if you want to use your current form:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {            
     this.TopMost = true;          
     this.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Comment: Yes, That's what I do with this.TopMost, but the problem is the second screen, the application only opens on one screen