# Start and change the coordinates of the window

Tags: window

I run some application like this:

```
string exeOne = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
IntPtr onePtr = Process.Start(exeOne).Handle;
```

I need to somehow change its location (output to another monitor). I may not know the name of the window in advance. How can I do that?

I looked at these questions, but I do not know what to do:

[Launch an application and send it to second monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113/launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor)

[How to enumerate all windows belonging to a particular process using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net)