# Application auto run on 2nd monitor with windows startup

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to make an application auto-run on 2nd monitor with windows startup?
I have a small C# application which runs 24/7 on my 2nd monitor, I was trying to make it auto run with windows startup.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this an application you wrote?

Comment: Both WinForms and WPF provide a way for you to specify the monitor that a `Form` or `Window` appears on which you can do in the `Load` event.

Comment: Does this help? [Launch an application and send it to second monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113/launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor)

Comment: I already went through that, it says move it by invoking the Windows API and use FindWindow to retrieve the handle to the window. But i dont think its gonna help e.

Comment: @Dour High Arch 
Yes.. i wrote this application