# C# Select default screen for separate process

Tags: c#, location, screen, default, startup

Is there a way to designate the start up location of an external process?  I am trying to select the screen BEFORE the application launches, NOT move it afterwards.

When start the process and then move the window from one screen to another (programatically or manually) it resizes the window but not the content of that window because they are different resolutions.

I don't have control of the resolution of the screens or selection of which one is primary.

This question is similar to, but not the same as:
  [Launch an application and send it to second monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113/c-launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor)
  [Launch an application and send it to second monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797154/launch-an-application-and-send-it-to-second-monitor)

Comment: So what is that you are looking for in addition to the post?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to select in which screen another program launches.

Answer (score 0):

May be I understand what you mean.

You want that external programm appears immediately in the screen you want, so you will get rid of resolution mananagement bug of the program, cause this is a bug, if content of the window doesn't reflect resolution changes of host window.

There is no way to do that, that I'm aware of. In fact solutions linked by you first load program, find window and finally move where needed.

If this is not what you're actually asking for, please explain better your intentions.

Comment: You are correct, I am trying to compensate for the error in the application that I am launching. I was hoping that someone might have a solution other than moving the window.

Comment: @Insomnialex Dont't really think it's possible, unless application itself has something implemented inside, so you can run that nested code by passing arguments, for example.

Comment: I wasn't able to pass arguments, but I was able to edit a configuration file in which a setting was disabling the correct resizing of the content of the application. This by itself didn't work, but the resolution of the content was also an editable field. I selected a size larger than the window itself and it seems to force it over to the correct screen.  This is by no means a real solution to the actual issue of choosing a screen to start an external process in, but a hack that worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to decide location a windows program launches but you don't want to move it after the program starts.

Usually a program remembers its previous position when it closes in registry for next launch. I would control that. For more information, refer to http://www.mywindowsclub.com/resources/3016-Start-up-position-programs-Windows.aspx

Comment: The application being started isn't registered in the registry and trying to manually input the info didn't work for me, but I was probably doing it wrong. I eventually ended up finding another solution for my issue specifically - not really a solution, but a hack that works in my case. I'll detail it in the other response because it has more to do with the target application settings.